# Leverage Browser Caching in PageSpeed Insights with Varnish & Nginx

Tags: caching, nginx

Does anyone know how to remove the Leverage Browser Caching message from PageSpeed Insights using Varnish Cache and Nginx?

[Google PageSpeed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYHYr.png)

I've tried adding the location ~*... block to the server block but that crashed the site. I think I'm missing a Varnish setting but can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To override these headers and still put the element into cache for 2 minutes, the following configuration may be used:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (beresp.ttl < 120s) {
   set beresp.ttl = 120s;

   # Set the clients TTL on this object
   set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=120";
  }
}
```

Or, in Varnish 4.0 terms:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (beresp.ttl < 120s) {
    set beresp.ttl = 120s;
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=120";
  }
}
```